# Intersection between a line and a n dimensional parallelotope

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Suppose that I have a line in an $n$ dimensional space described by
$$ X=A+Bk, \quad \quad X,A,B \in \mathbb{R}^n, k \in \mathbb{R} $$
here $A$ is known and I want to find all the possible vectors $B$ such that this line has one and only one intersection with the set $S$ described by: 
$$S=\{ X \in \mathbb{R}^n \: | \: 0 \le X \le W\} $$ where $W \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$ and the inequalities are to be intended component-wise.

Is there any closed-form formula for such vectors $B$?

Comment: Otherwise said, you desire to get the contour of set $S$ as seen from viewpoint $A$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that there is a closed-form formula. But computationally, it's not that hard.  Since $A$ lies outside the cuboid, there is at least one coordinate $i$, that either $A_i<0$ or $A_i>W_i$. Let's take $A_1<0$ (other cases can be brought to it).

Take plane $x_1=0$ and project all the $2^n$ vertices $v$ of the cuboid to this plane along the line connecting the vertex and point $A$:

$$
v_i'= \frac{v_1A_i-v_iA_1}{v_1-A_1}
$$

Then we calculate convex hull of all those projected vertices. All lines from $A$ to this convex hull will have only one intersection with cuboid $S$.

Comment: [+1] very clean solution.